# Prove that every zero of $g$ is also a zero of $f$ of the same multiplicity with $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$,$g:{z:|z|<1}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic functions such that $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ for all $|z|<1$. Prove that every zero of $g$ is also a zero of $f$ of the same multiplicity and that thus $f=\lambda g$ for some $|\lambda|=1$.

My proof sketch: It's easy to see zeros of $f$(denote as $Z(f)$) and $g$ are same, denote it as $a$. If $Z(f)=B(0,1)$, trivial. If $a$ is an isolated point, there exists a small enough disk $B(a,r)$ on which we can
write $f(z)=(z-a)^m \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_{m+j}(z-a)^j=(z-a)^mp(z)$ and
$g(z)=(z-a)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{n+k}(z-a)^k=(z-a)^nq(z)$. If $m \neq n$, suppose $m>n$, then by the equation we can get $|(z-a)^{m-n}|=|q(z)/p(z)|$ on $B(a,r) \backslash \{a\}$. Then when $z\rightarrow a$, LHS goes to 0 and RHS is close to $c_n/b_m$, contradiction.

However, this proof does not use the condition that $|z|<1$, I cannot figure out where is wrong... Thank you!

Comment: It just gives you an open set to work with. You somehow used it when you are talking about the small disks.

Comment: What is $G$ ?..

Comment: @AlgRev, that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @lhf, modified, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $|z|=1$ to prove $f$ and $g$ have same zeros.  It is used to prove $f=\lambda g$ for some $|\lambda|=1$.

Since $f$ and $g$ have same zeros, $f/g$ is analytic in $|z|=1$. So $|f/g|$ reaches maximum on $|z|=1$ by maximum modulus principle. Likewise  $g/f$ is analytic in $|z|=1$ and reaches maximum on $|z|=1$.

So $|f/g|$ reaches maximum and minmum on $|z|=1$. Since $|f/g|=1$ on $|z|=1$, $f/g$ is constant in $|z|=1$. So $f=e^{i\theta}g$ and set $\lambda=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: so this also works for $|z|<2$? My proof is: $|f/g| =1$ $\forall z \in B(a,r)$ and $f/g$ is holomorphic on that disk, then we have $f/g$ equals a constant with modulus 1 because I remember a practice:"if $|f|$ is constant and holomorphic on a region then $f$ is a constant funtion"

Comment: yes, having same zero is not limited to unit disk.

Comment: thanks for your proof! maximum modulus principle is powerful!